# How to build HTML in Backbone app with Webpack

Tags: webpack, backbone.js

I'm trying to use Webpack on a small TODO application and it's failing to resolve the HTML template for the entry point JS file.

I have tried running the Backbone app as it is and it works fine so I'm thinking it's because it's being include by my entry point JS file and Webpack doesn't know how to handle it.

package.json

```
{
    "name": "backbone_webpack_demo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {},
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "backbone": "^0.9.9",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "jquery": "^1.7.1",
        "underscore": "^1.2.2",
        "webpack": "^4.28.4"
      }
    }
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports = {
      entry: ["./js/views/todo.js"],
      mode: 'development',
      output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
      },
      plugins : [ new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $ : "jquery",
          Backbone : "backbone",
          _ : "underscore"
      }) ]
    }
```

todo.js

```
define(['text!templates/todos.html'], function(todosTemplate){
    var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    //... is a list tag.
    tagName:  'li',

    // Cache the template function for a single item.
    template: _.template(todosTemplate),
```

The error shown is:

```
Hash: 682462a622281f1ff942
    Version: webpack 4.28.4
    Time: 1342ms
    Built at: 01/14/2019 12:48:05 PM
     1 asset
    Entrypoint main = bundle.js
    [1] multi ./js/views/todo.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./js/views/todo.js 2.39 KiB {0} [built]
    [4] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [5] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
        + 2 hidden modules

    ERROR in ./js/views/todo.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'templates/todos.html' in '/home/steve/backbone-fundamentals/practicals/modular-todo-app/js/views'
     @ ./js/views/todo.js 1:0-82:2
     @ multi ./js/views/todo.js
```

The code builds just fine as a standalone Backbone app not using Webpack

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this old github discussion](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1046#issuecomment-272643129)

webpack.config.js

```
resolveLoader: {
  alias: {
      text: 'text-loader'
  }
}
```

Also going to need [text-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-loader).

You might have to make adjustments according to your webpack version.

Comment: Hi. I have tried this. I installed text-loader -> npm i text-loader —save-dev, updated web pack.config.js and re-ran webpack command but still getting -> ERROR in ./js/views/todo.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'templates/todos.html' in '/home/Steve/backbone-fundamentals/practicals/modular-todo-app/js/views'
 @ ./js/views/todo.js 1:0-82:2
 @ multi ./js/views/todo.js